# Big Query DDL Command to Create Table From Existing One?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I Need to Create A Temp Table in BigQuery Using DDL Command But While I Write The Statement as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DataSet.newtable1 (x INT64, y STRUCT<a ARRAY<STRING>, b BOOL>)
 PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
 OPTIONS(
   expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
   partition_expiration_days=1,
   description="a table that expires in 2020, with each partition living for 24 hours",
   labels=[("org_unit", "development")]
 ) As SELECT * FROM DATASET.newTable
```

I Got A Response as CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is not supported
Any Alternative So I can Achieve my Goal to Create a Temp Table As Per Requirement and And Delete It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statements is [`under development`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#features_under_development)

Meantime, you can just create table using DDL and then you either use it as destination table for your `SELECT * FROM DATASET.newTable` or alternatively you can use DML

```
INSERT DATASET.newTable1 (x INT64, y STRUCT<a ARRAY<STRING>, b BOOL>)
SELECT *
FROM DATASET.newTable
```

Comment: Is CREATE OR REPLACE (or just CREATE) TABLE still under development?  I get the following error: "BadRequest: 400 Cannot set destination table in jobs with DDL statements" when trying to write overwrite an existing table with a temporary table .